# Quick Explode Keyframes

Tags: keyframes, effects, timeline

I'm experimenting with quick explode. Everything works fine but I can't find the according keyframes in the timeline. I want the explosion to happen just a few keyframes later/earlier. How do I do that? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object, go to particles tab:

[image]

Change start and end frame to the value you want. e.g. both to 50.